# Fail to post login data to external site

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication

I'm trying to make a link to connect to my partner's website.  To do so I want to POST my login credentials from my website to their website (https://www.solven.pe/funcionarios/login). The problem is that I cannot make it work, I get redirected to homepage instead. Is it there any solution for me?

```html
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="https://www.solven.pe/funcionarios/login" method="post" target="_blank">      
<input style="display:none;" type="text" id="exampleInputEmail22" name="email" value="xxx">
<input style="display:none;" type="password" id="exampleInputPassword42" name="password"  value="xxx">
 <button id="loginButton" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ir a Solven">Ingresar</button>
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: This has to do with your partner's web server, not yours.

Comment: The best would be to use javascritp to make a request call with form data to partners website, then after getting response do stuff in your website.